# Default page when opening SharePoint Online from Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-team-site, edit-links

When selecting "Open in SharePoint" from the menu in the top right corner of a Team (shown below), is there anyway to change what page on SharePoint is linked?

It defaults to Documents > General, but I'd like it to navigate to our SharePoint home page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test, it's by design.

Currently, there is no option to change the directed link for "Open in SharePoint".

Comment: Thanks Emily. Too bad it can't be changed, but I appreciate the response. Saves me some time trying to find a solution that does not exist.